# How to Define Common Resources Across WPF Applications (including templates)?

Tags: wpf, resources, controltemplate, staticresource, app.xaml

I am looking for a way to define a WPF resource (for now, to be used as a static resource) that is accessible from everywhere within my application.

My resource is defined in this resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="flatButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The selected answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703026/shared-resource-dictionary-between-several-user-controls-and-across-assemblies/705061) indicates that I must merge that resource dictionary into my `App.xaml` file (of a project called `AppWideResources`):

```
<Application x:Class="AppWideResources.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/AppWideResources;component/CommonResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

At first, this seems to work; the button in this window is appropriately styled in a flat way with an extra-thick border:

```
<Window x:Class="AppWideResources.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="AppWideResources" Height="300" Width="300"
    >
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource flatButtonStyle}" Content="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**However**, this stops working as soon as I use my shared resource in a control template:

My (extremely simplified, for the purpose of this question) control:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace AppWideResources
{
    public class MyControl : Control
    {
        static MyControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
        }
    }
}
```

... and the corresponding `Themes\Generic.xaml` file:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppWideResources">

    <Style TargetType="local:MyControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource flatButtonStyle}" Content="1"/>
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource flatButtonStyle}" Content="2"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

This control is then inserted into my window:

```
<Window x:Class="AppWideResources.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppWideResources"
    Title="AppWideResources" Height="300" Width="300"
    >
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource flatButtonStyle}" Content="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <local:MyControl/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If I run this, a [`XamlParseException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlparseexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is thrown, saying that the static resource `flatButtonStyle` cannot be found.

The only workaround I have found is by explicitly merging the common resource dictionary into the local resource dictionary of the control template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/AppWideResources;component/CommonResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource flatButtonStyle}" Content="1"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource flatButtonStyle}" Content="2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However, not only is this quite verbose and error-prone with several lines of redundant code (my actual project contains quite a few templated controls, not just one), I am also concerned about wasting system resources by loading the static resources several times (once for every time `CommonResources.xaml` is included). (Is that concern justified? Or does WPF use the same instances every time when loading a particular resource dictionary?)

So, the question is: **What is the proper way to make a WPF resource accessible throughout the whole application, including control templates?**

Comment: Is answer provided not good enough mate?

Comment: @RohitVats: Patience ;-) I've seen your answer and it works, and I'm probably going to accept it; I just tend to leave questions open for another day or so, just in case someone else suggests an even better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**StaticResource** will be resolved and assigned to the property during the loading of the XAML which occurs before the application is actually run. So, `static resource has to be available at the time of loading`.

It works for normal button since resource look up continues till application resources and resolve it from there. But `MyControl template still not loaded into app visual tree so it can't traverse upto application resources`.

*There are two ways to achieve that:*

1. Merge ResourceDictionary in Generic.xaml as well which you have already achieved.
2. Other way is to use **DynamicResource** which assigns an Expression object to the property during loading but does not actually lookup the resource until runtime when the Expression object is asked for the value. This `defers looking up the resource until it is needed at runtime`.

Read it here -  [StaticResource v/s DynamicResource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200875/632337).

This will **work without merging dictionaries in Generic.xaml**:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource flatButtonStyle}" Content="1"/>
<Button Style="{DynamicResource flatButtonStyle}" Content="2"/>
```